# How to achieve a good performing grouping algorithm along distance criterion in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, grouping

## Introduction

Good day,

I am looking for a grouping algorithm that can do the following:

Let's suppose I have an array of sorted numbers (without any multiple occurences). For example, {0, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10}.

I want to make groups from that array, such that:

1. I minimize the number of groups,
2. Each groups needs to contain numbers that are linked with at most **n - 1** "bonds" (for example, n = 3, 0 and 2 are neighbours but not 0 and 3).

---

**EDIT**

In other words, when I say neighbours, I should speak about integer distance. For example, the distance of 0 to 2 i 2 (and vice versa). The distance of 0 to 3 is 3. You could think of the problem like a set of 1D points, and one needs to find the minimal number of centers, which center contains points that are distant to it of n/2. I hope it is more clear like that.

---

The example has multiple groups possible but the best along conditions 1 and 2 (n = 3) is {{0, 2}, {5, 6, 7}, {10}}. {{0}, {2, 5}, {6, 7}, {10}} has one group more than the best solution. The ideal solution would happen if all sorted numbers are continuous:

```
nb_groups* = ceil(v.size() / n);
```

In addition, there might be multiple solution depending on the algorithm.

---

## What I tried

For now, what I do is:

1. Compute the array of the distances between the neighbouring elemens,
2. Check neighbouring conditions with rests from the beginning of the vector to the end (see the code below).

It seems to work (to me), but I was wondering two things:

1. Does it really work for any cases (have maybe not tested all cases?)?
2. If so, could I optimize my implementation in a way (better than in.size() - 1 iteration ans with less memory consumption)?

---

## Code

I was considering a function that takes the vector to group, and the max distance. This function would return the indices of the first element of the group.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> groupe(const std::vector<int>& at, const int& n);

int main() {
    // Example of input vector
    std::vector<int> in = {0, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 22, 30, 50, 51};
    // Try to group with neighbouring distance of 3
    std::vector<int> res = groupe(in, 3);
    

    // Printing the result
    for(const int& a : res) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }
    
}

std::vector<int> groupe(const std::vector<int>& at, const int& n) {
    std::vector<int> out;
    
    // Reste keeps tracks of a bigger neighbouring distance (in case we can look for another element to be in the group)
    int reste(0);
    size_t s = at.size() - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        // Computing the distance between element i and i + 1
        int d = at[i + 1] - at[i];
        
        if(d >= n) {
            if(reste == 0) {
                out.push_back(i);
            }
            reste = 0;
        } else {
            if(reste == 0) {
                out.push_back(i);
            }
            reste += d;
            if(reste >= n) {
                reste = 0;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    if(reste == 0 || reste >= n) {
        out.push_back(s);
    }
    
    return out;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0 2 5 7 8 9
```

---

## Note

If the original vector was not sorted, I guess we could have sorted it first and then achieved this step (or maybe there is another algorithm mor efficient?).

---

I thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: its not quite clear what you mean with "bonds". "(for example, n = 3, 0 and 2 are neighbours but not 0 and 3)."   hm?!? 3,0 and 2 are neighbors but 0 and 3 are not? Why?

Comment: Sorry if this was not clear. What I meant is that the distance from 0 to 2 is 2 "bonds" (2 - 0). While for 0 and 3 this is 3 (3 - 0).

Comment: Do you have an example where simple greedy algorithm would fail? [seems to work ok](https://godbolt.org/z/vGY1jPcaq). I can't find example where greedy algorithm doesn't provide optimal solution.

Comment: @MarekR Not for now, and that was part of my question if you could see one case where it would fail.
Ok thanks then my first question seems to be answered. And do you see any optimization improvements?